# Android different styles for different versions android and screens

Tags: java, android, mobile

Sorry if this question smb asked before me but I couldn't find answer.
I wanna support different screens and android versions in one apk.
I read reference about support different screens and versions android.

As I understood I can create dir values with postfix -v7(for example). And this style will be chosen for android with version7. And it works....
But what if I wanna create different styles for different screen in 7th sdk.

I can create values with postfix -large or -small or smth else. But How can I specify this values with values-v7(for android with 7th sdk)? 
Or android will do it automaticaly?

I need values-v7, cause I specify parent style for my application(for android 2 it's nothing, but for Android 3 or hight it's holo)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the android dev resource at [Providing Alternate Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources)

For eg, you can have a directory **layout-large-hdpi-v7** with layout files. It says the layout files are for a large screen with hdpi density and supports version 7 and above.

Answer (score 2):

You can append as many resources folder postfix as you want separated by dashes, but you have to list them in the order indicated by this table http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2

so you can do something like this for example

```
style-large-v7
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you guys! This's what I need. It's very good that I can multiply these configuration.  Thank's a lot!!!